# Wrong popup transition when UIImagePickerController is being presented in a UIPopoverPresentationController on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I was trying to present a `UIImagePickerController` with source type `.PhotoLibrary` on iPad. Following [Apple's recommendation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller), it's presented in a popover by using `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

Here is the actual method for presenting the image picker:

```
func openImagePicker(with sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, from button: UIButton) {
    guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType) else {
        return
    }

    guard let mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(sourceType) else {
        return
    }

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = sourceType
    picker.mediaTypes = mediaTypes
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    if let popover = picker.popoverPresentationController {
        popover.sourceView = button
        popover.sourceRect = button.bounds
    }
}
```

The issue I noticed, particularly on iPad in landscape mode, is that when I went into an album and tapped Back button to go back, the popup transition animation looks like the view is flying off the screen, which is totally weird.

[image]

It only happens on landscape. No issue on portrait mode.

I tried searching for similar issues but couldn't find any. Does anyone encounter the same problem, and how did you fix it?